# How can I get list of lists of total case for each country by month?

Tags: python, csv, data-science, heatmap

I'm thinking on this for an hours, I tried many different ways, but since this csv file is too complicated for me (im beginner), i couldn't do. I need multidimensional array of total case for each country by month. After solving this, I will use these array in place of values to create heat map.

To be more clear, for example France
I need something like this totalcases_France= (total cases in december, total cases in january, .... total cases in november)
I need to do this for each country and get multidimensional array.
[ACCESS CSV FILE FROM HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hbtfqMxI_nQJ-A_0D_f39TICD6sIKwd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you only wanting to use pure python or are you wanting to use third party packages? Cause there are data science packages that work great for this stuff.

Comment: @Mythalorian I have to use pandas, numpy etc.

Comment: maybe try to do it only for one country and later you can covnert this to function which you could run in loop with other countries. BTW: as know `pandas.DataFrame` can keep only two-dimensional table and you may need them to keep on list or dictionary - ie. `{"france": df_france, "germany": df_germany}` OR maybe you should all values keep rather in 2D-table

Comment: I don't know if you mean `all new cases only in december` but you should convert date to `year-month` and then you can group by this value (pandas has function `group_by`) and sum `new_cases` to get `all new cases only in december`, `all new cases only in january`, `all new cases only in february`,

Comment: @furas yes group_by is the solution i want, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean sum in month

- sum of all cases only in december,
- sum of all cases only in january,
- sum of all cases only in february,
  etc.

or cumulative sum

- sum of all cases in december,
- sum of all cases in december + january,
- sum of all cases in december + january + february
  etc.

For both I would use column `new cases` and `pandas` with `groupby(['location', 'year-month'])`

First I need to create `year-month` from `year-month-day`

```
df['year-month'] = df['date'].str[:7]
```

And next I can group

```
groups = df.groupby(['location', 'year-month'])
```

and sum `new_cases` to get sum of only new cases

```
df_sum = groups.sum().reset_index()[['location', 'year-month', 'new_cases']]
```

Result

```
         location year-month  new_cases
0     Afghanistan    2019-12        0.0
1     Afghanistan    2020-01        0.0
2     Afghanistan    2020-02        1.0
3     Afghanistan    2020-03      140.0
4     Afghanistan    2020-04     1808.0
...           ...        ...        ...
2112     Zimbabwe    2020-07     2518.0
2113     Zimbabwe    2020-08     3320.0
2114     Zimbabwe    2020-09     1425.0
2115     Zimbabwe    2020-10      525.0
2116     Zimbabwe    2020-11      858.0
```

and I can use it with `cumsum()` to get total/cumulative sum

```
df_sum['total_cases'] = df_sum.groupby('location')['new_cases'].cumsum()
```

Result

```
         location year-month  new_cases  total_cases
0     Afghanistan    2019-12        0.0          0.0
1     Afghanistan    2020-01        0.0          0.0
2     Afghanistan    2020-02        1.0          1.0
3     Afghanistan    2020-03      140.0        141.0
4     Afghanistan    2020-04     1808.0       1949.0
...           ...        ...        ...          ...
2112     Zimbabwe    2020-07     2518.0       3092.0
2113     Zimbabwe    2020-08     3320.0       6412.0
2114     Zimbabwe    2020-09     1425.0       7837.0
2115     Zimbabwe    2020-10      525.0       8362.0
2116     Zimbabwe    2020-11      858.0       9220.0
```

Evetually later I can get only one country

```
df_sum[ df_sum['location'] == 'France' ]

df_sum[ df_sum['location'] == 'Germany' ]
```

Result

```
    location year-month  new_cases  total_cases
671   France    2019-12        0.0          0.0
672   France    2020-01        6.0          6.0
673   France    2020-02       51.0         57.0
674   France    2020-03    44493.0      44550.0
675   France    2020-04    83892.0     128442.0
676   France    2020-05    23054.0     151496.0
677   France    2020-06    12764.0     164260.0
678   France    2020-07    22313.0     186573.0
679   France    2020-08    91370.0     277943.0
680   France    2020-09   272747.0     550690.0
681   France    2020-10   781294.0    1331984.0
682   France    2020-11   808224.0    2140208.0

    location year-month  new_cases  total_cases
722  Germany    2019-12        0.0          0.0
723  Germany    2020-01        5.0          5.0
724  Germany    2020-02       52.0         57.0
725  Germany    2020-03    61856.0      61913.0
726  Germany    2020-04    97206.0     159119.0
727  Germany    2020-05    22363.0     181482.0
728  Germany    2020-06    12777.0     194259.0
729  Germany    2020-07    14439.0     208698.0
730  Germany    2020-08    33683.0     242381.0
731  Germany    2020-09    46838.0     289219.0
732  Germany    2020-10   229534.0     518753.0
733  Germany    2020-11   410380.0     929133.0
```

Or I could use `groupby(['locations'])` to split to separated list dataframes and create dictionary `{"France": df_frances, "Germany": df_germany, ...}`

```
data = {}

for country, values in groups:
    data[country] = values
```

---

Full code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')
print(df.columns)

df['year-month'] = df['date'].str[:7]
#print(df['year-month'].head())

groups = df.groupby(['location', 'year-month'])

df_sum = groups.sum().reset_index()[['location', 'year-month', 'new_cases']]
#print(df_sum)

df_sum['total_cases'] = df_sum.groupby('location')['new_cases'].cumsum()
print(df_sum)


print(df_sum[ df_sum['location'] == 'France' ])

print(df_sum[ df_sum['location'] == 'Germany' ])

data = {}

for country, values in groups:
    data[country] = values

print(data)
```

Comment: I was looking for first one, I was trying to do it using loops (which was so long and I got so many errors). Looks like loops are not efficient with these kind of big files, thank you so much for help!

Comment: yes, loops are not  effective - pandas in own functions uses code created in C/C++ which is faster.